# Can "all()" function be applied to sub-matrices?[MATLAB]

Tags: matlab

If I have  a `matrix A` with `size (1000,3)`.

Say, the sub-matrices are of sizes `(100,3)`, that is there are 10 sub-matrices.

I want to use `all(A,2)` to evaluate the `A` column-wise, such that `all()` should return `10` separate results corresponding to each sub-matrices.

The reason why I need separate results is to run this code

```
length(nonzeros(all(A,2)))/400
```

That means, finally, `length()` should return 10 values, corresponding to each sub-matrices.

Answer (score 2):

You can `reshape` your data and then call `all` along the first and third dimensions.

```
all(all(reshape(A, 100, [], size(A, 2)), 1), 3)
```

Alternately, you could first transpose `A` and `reshape` before calling `all`.

```
all(reshape(A.', [], 10), 1)
```

If you just want the percentage of non-zeros in each sub matrix, you can compute the `sum` of a `logical`.

```
nRows = size(A,2) * 100;
out = sum(reshape(A.', nRows, []) ~= 0, 1) / nRows;
```

Comment: I think the 'reshape' is messing with my sub-matrixes. The sub-matrixes have to be of the size, say, `(100,3)`. And say if `all(a(100,3),2)`, then I should get a column vector, showing either a `0` or `1` depending on if a row 'i' has non-zeros elements in all its three columns.  The thing is, I want to use `all()` to calculate for each sub-matrices at the same time. The third option is the closest to what I want, that is the percentage of non-zeros in each sub-matrix but only if the there are non-zero elements in each columns.

Comment: I worked around your suggestions and found out that `out   = sum(reshape( all(A,2),1000,10) ~=0)/1000;` gives me the deisred output.